# Disable PDF.js and use Evince instead

Tags: firefox, evince

Some PDFs render inside Firefox. I am very unhappy with that for several reasons.

Since Ubuntu ships with a good, stable and lightweight PDF-viewer, evince, I'd rather have all PDFs handled by that native viewer instead of the Firefox one.

I suspect it's because of either the mine-type, some extension, a disposition-header or some combination thereof, but some PDFs open already just fine in Evince. Others still open in the PDF.js.

How can I direct *all* PDFs to the native, evince, viewer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd rather not use the built-in PDF Viewer, you can use another PDF viewer like Evince or another default viewer on Ubuntu.

To switch from the built-in PDF viewer to another PDF viewer:

1. At the top of the Firefox window, click on the *Edit menu* and select *Preferences*
2. Select the *Applications panel*.
3. Find **Portable Document Format** (PDF) in the list and click on it to select it.
4. Click on the drop-down arrow in the **Action** column for the above entry and select the PDF viewer you wish to use.
5. Click *Close* to close the Preferences window

[image]

(Source https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-built-pdf-viewer-and-use-another-viewer)

Comment: Thanks. I went one step "further" and chose "/usr/bin/gnome-open" instead. This means that Gnome (Ubuntu) will always choose the application that is set system-wide as PDF-viewer. On vanilla Ubuntu that will be "Evince, Document Viewer", but when I  were to choose another PDF-reader Firefox will respect that change.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be a setting in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

It's this entry thats needs to be modified:

```
application/octet-stream=gedit.desktop (it may look different on your machine)
```

As soon as I changed this to:

```
application/octet-stream=evince.desktop;gedit.desktop
```

firefox would suggest to open a .pdf file with evince instead of gedit